# how to give bordercolor to a selected widget in gridview builder using Obx Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-getx, stream-builder

i have a list of items coming from firebase firestore collection in gridview builder. i need to give bordercolor to only the selected items(like favourite icon , when user clicks,color of the selected icon from list changes.like wise i need to change the border color).using Obx Getx.

here is my getx controller page

```
class PetSellController extends GetxController{
  final petType = <SaleModel>[].obs;
  final isClicked = false.obs;
  final  selectedIndex = 0.obs;

@override
void onInit() async {
  petType.bindStream(listType());
  super.onInit();
}

Stream <List<SaleModel>> listType() {

 
  Stream <QuerySnapshot> stream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pet_category').snapshots();

  return stream.map((qShot) => qShot.docs
    .map((doc) => SaleModel(
      image: doc['title'],
      icon: doc['pet_icon'],
      title: doc['title']))
    .toList());
}
}
```

below is the part  where i call the obx

```
Obx(()=> GridView.builder(
                      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:15,vertical: 10),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                        mainAxisExtent: 100
                      ),
                      itemCount:controller.petType.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      
                        return GestureDetector(//////////here is ontap function
                          onTap: (){
                          controller.isClicked.value =! controller.isClicked.value; 
                          print(controller.isClicked);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(//////// here is where i put condition
                            border: controller.isClicked.value == false?  Border.all(
                              width: 3,
                              color:  Colors.black,
                            ): null,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: AppColor.surface
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height:maxHeight*.1,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image:NetworkImage(controller.petType[index].icon))
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(controller.petType[index].title),
                            ],
                          ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
      )
```

the value of onClicked is  changing when i click on a item.i can see this in debug console using print statement.But UI only changes after hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan to change the border colour of the GridView item, you can move the Obx down to the `itemBuilder`. Simply wrap the `Container` **inside** the `GestureDetector` with an Obx.

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      // change your variable here
    },
    child: Obx(() => Container(//your code here))
  );
}
```

Comment: the above code works but when I go back to the previous screen and return there is no data in the grid view builder. I think its because of the item count.